# Dynamically create chart with Chart.js and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

We're currently using customerthermometers to survey our customers after completed support-tickets. Unfortunately customerthermometers widget's look disgusting. So I'm currently trying to create a chart with Chart.js and dynamically getting data from customerthermometers' API with PHP.

All parts in the PHP-array ($dataPoints) is taken into account in the chart, except the "data", and I really don't know how to proceed further.

```php
<?php
$gold = file_get_contents( 'https://app.customerthermometer.com/api.php?apiKey=<api_key>&getMethod=getNumResponsesValue&temperatureID=1' );
$green = file_get_contents( 'https://app.customerthermometer.com/api.php?apiKey=<api_key>&getMethod=getNumResponsesValue&temperatureID=2' );
$yellow = file_get_contents( 'https://app.customerthermometer.com/api.php?apiKey=<api_key>&getMethod=getNumResponsesValue&temperatureID=3' );
$red = file_get_contents( 'https://app.customerthermometer.com/api.php?apiKey=<api_key>&getMethod=getNumResponsesValue&temperatureID=4' );

$dataPoints = array(
  array( "label" => "Gold Star" , "data" => $gold , "backgroundColor" => "rgba(255,215,0,1)"),
  array( "label" => "Green Light" , "data" => $green , "backgroundColor" => "rgba(0,128,0,1)"),
  array( "label" => "Yellow Light" , "data" => $yellow , "backgroundColor" => "rgba(255,255,0,1)"),
  array( "label" => "Red Light" , "data" => $red , "backgroundColor" => "rgba(255,0,0,1)" )
);
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Chart Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/chart28/dist/Chart.js"></script>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="100" height="20"></canvas>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Gold Star', 'Green Light', 'Yellow Light', 'Red Light'],
        datasets: <?php echo json_encode($dataPoints, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
</script>
    <?php echo json_encode($dataPoints, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit:
`$dataPoints`

```
[{"label":"Gold Star","data":4,"backgroundColor":"rgba(255,215,0,1)"},{"label":"Green Light","data":2,"backgroundColor":"rgba(0,128,0,1)"},{"label":"Yellow Light","data":0,"backgroundColor":"rgba(255,255,0,1)"},{"label":"Red Light","data":0,"backgroundColor":"rgba(255,0,0,1)"}]
```

I've also tried to statically set the following values within `datasets`, and this works and gives me the desired result:

```
datasets: [{
    data: [ 4 , 2 , 0 , 0 ],
    backgroundColor: [
        "rgba(255,215,0,1)",
        "rgba(0,128,0,1)",
        "rgba(255,255,0,1)",
        "rgba(255,0,0,1)"
    ]

}]
```

Working code (Thanks to @Camille):

```php
<?php
$gold = file_get_contents( 'https://app.customerthermometer.com/api.php?apiKey=<api_key>&getMethod=getNumResponsesValue&temperatureID=1' );
$green = file_get_contents( 'https://app.customerthermometer.com/api.php?apiKey=<api_key>&getMethod=getNumResponsesValue&temperatureID=2' );
$yellow = file_get_contents( 'https://app.customerthermometer.com/api.php?apiKey=<api_key>&getMethod=getNumResponsesValue&temperatureID=3' );
$red = file_get_contents( 'https://app.customerthermometer.com/api.php?apiKey=<api_key>&getMethod=getNumResponsesValue&temperatureID=4' );

$dataPoints = array(
  array( "data" => array($gold) , "label" => "Gold Star" , "backgroundColor" => "rgba(255,215,0,1)"),
  array( "data" => array($green) , "label" => "Green Light" , "backgroundColor" => "rgba(0,128,0,1)"),
  array( "data" => array($yellow) , "label" => "Yellow Light" , "backgroundColor" => "rgba(255,255,0,1)"),
  array( "data" => array($red) , "label" => "Red Light" , "backgroundColor" => "rgba(255,0,0,1)" )
);

?>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/chart28/dist/Chart.js"></script>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="100" height="20"></canvas>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Customer Thermometer'],
        datasets: <?php echo json_encode($dataPoints, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But you have verified that those `data` entries actually contain what you expect to begin with, right? Meaning, that $gold, $green etc. actually have the values you expected, and that those requests did not somehow fail in the first place?

Comment: @04FS The customerthermometer API provides a plain text integer.
Added `$dataPoints`-array to my edit.

Comment: Did you try this with static data first? Figure out what data structure you need to get your desired output from the chart.js library, before you start involving PHP/anything dynamic?

Comment: @04FS check the latest edit.

Comment: That is _completely_ different from what you are creating dynamically here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data attribute of `$dataPoints` should be an array. You have to convert it if you get a single value

```
...
$dataPoints = array(
  array( "label" => "Gold Star" , "data" => array($gold) , "backgroundColor" => "rgba(255,215,0,1)"),
  array( "label" => "Green Light" , "data" => array($green) , "backgroundColor" => "rgba(0,128,0,1)"),
  array( "label" => "Yellow Light" , "data" => array($yellow) , "backgroundColor" => "rgba(255,255,0,1)"),
  array( "label" => "Red Light" , "data" => array($red) , "backgroundColor" => "rgba(255,0,0,1)" )
);
...
```